# Javascript - Change text back to original after double click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm pretty much a novice when it comes to Javascript so bear with me.

I have a button which will open up a div, which then displays a list of cities, then I implemented a text change to "View Areas Covered -" which also works fine. However I have come into trouble when trying to close the div and return the text to the original which is "View Areas Covered +"

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $("#divArea").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#areasCovered").fadeToggle(1000);
            document.getElementById("h3Class").innerHTML = "View Areas Covered -";
        }); 
    });

    function() {
        $("#divArea").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#areasCovered").fadeToggle(1000);

            if (document.getElementById("h3Class").value = "View Areas Covered -" == true) {
                document.getElementById("h3Class").innerHTML = "View Areas Covered +";
            }; else {

            }
        }); 
    });
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="well well-sm">                  
    <div id="divArea" class="img-responsive" >
        <a href="#"><h3>View Areas Covered +</h3></a>
        <div id ="areasCovered" class="img-responsive">
            <p  class="paragraph1"> //list of cities </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: This lloks easy. However I don't understand what you want to do. Can you show the HTML and explain what happens, and when it happens with the HTML?

Comment: Your if clause looks ugly, you don't have to check for == true, try document.getElementById("h3Class").value == "View Areas Covered -"

Comment: is your JavaScript valid at all ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your logic a bit, no need for two click-handlers. Here I'm adding a simple css-class to tell if the areas are toggled or not. Also if you use jQuery, no need to use getElementById

```
$(function () {
    $("#divArea").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).find("h3").text($(this).is(".js-clicked") ? "View Areas Covered +" : "View Areas Covered -");
        $(this).toggleClass("js-clicked");
        $(this).find("#areasCovered").fadeToggle(1000);
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/secvernb/1/)

Comment: Thanks, this works - However when I click it, the page moves to the top, which it didnt do before and im trying to avoid to improve user experience. Is there a fix for that?

Comment: (The action is at the bottom of the page)

Comment: I removed the preventDefault, since I didn't know you had a link there before I saw the html, add that and it works.

Comment: @Dog124 yes Esa's code works, but do you at least understand **why** your code did not work in the first place ? Since you begin with JavaScript, I think that's the most important part for you. If you don't, then you'll have to ask questions on SO over and over again because you don't understand where the problem is, and you can't solve it on your own. Please always keep in mind that SO is not a copy/paste site. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your document ready is wrong, use this syntax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#divArea").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#areasCovered").fadeToggle(1000);

        if (document.getElementById("h3Class").value = "View Areas Covered -" == true) {
            document.getElementById("h3Class").innerHTML = "View Areas Covered +";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("h3Class").innerHTML = "View Areas Covered -";
        }
    });      
});
```

This should work.

Editted:
Added else statement

Editted 2:
Cleaned code a bit

Comment: Thanks for the input - However, when I try this the fade toggle refuses to work

Comment: I suggest you should get your JS validated. I saw some lost ";" here and there. Other than that, I haven't really touched your fadeToggle(). If it doesnt work, try using fadeIn() and fadeOut()? I need more info bout your fading to know what it does.

Answer (score 0):

Your if-statement seems to be a bit messed up. Try comparing the value directly instead of checking for "true":

```
if (document.getElementById("h3Class").value == "View Areas Covered -") {
  // do something
}
```

You also don't need two different clicks handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your if condition, you don't have to check for == true, and you have to compare the strings with "==" instead of "=".

```
if (document.getElementById("h3Class").value = "View Areas Covered -" == true) {
    document.getElementById("h3Class").innerHTML = "View Areas Covered +";
};
```

Try this:

```
if (document.getElementById("h3Class").value == "View Areas Covered -") {
    document.getElementById("h3Class").innerHTML = "View Areas Covered +";
};
```

OR

```
if (document.getElementById("h3Class").innerHTML == "View Areas Covered -") {
    document.getElementById("h3Class").innerHTML = "View Areas Covered +";
};
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You JavaScript code is wrong in multiple ways:

- first of all, when I execute it I get "function statement requires a name" (wait, what ?!)
- there is a `;` at the end of you `if` statement, making your `else` statement totally useless
- why are you declaring two function with almost the exact same content ?
- you're declaring a function with no name, but you never use it
- your if statement is incorrect, you have both an `=` and an `==` signs in it: what do you want to test really test ?

I'll show how, from your code, I try to fix issues one after one other:

Here's your initial code:

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $("#divArea").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#areasCovered").fadeToggle(1000);
            document.getElementById("h3Class").innerHTML = "View Areas Covered -";
        }); 
    });

    function() {
        $("#divArea").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#areasCovered").fadeToggle(1000);

            if (document.getElementById("h3Class").value = "View Areas Covered -" == true) {
                document.getElementById("h3Class").innerHTML = "View Areas Covered +";
            }; else {

            }
        }); 
    });
```

First of all, when in doubt with your code, it's a bit better to externalize your "document.ready" code in a named function:

```
// I've just taken the function in the $(document).ready call
// and externalize it with a name
function onReady() {
    $("#divArea").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#areasCovered").fadeToggle(1000);
        document.getElementById("h3Class").innerHTML = "View Areas Covered -";
    });
}

$(document).ready(onReady);

    // here you can see there is still a function with no name
    // why is that happening ? that's not correct
    function() {
        $("#divArea").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#areasCovered").fadeToggle(1000);

            if (document.getElementById("h3Class").value = "View Areas Covered -" == true) {
                document.getElementById("h3Class").innerHTML = "View Areas Covered +";
            }; else {

            }
        }); 
    });
```

Now, you can see this unammed unused function appears clearly. If it's unused, there's a problem elsewhere: it's logic should be in the `onReady` method:

```
function onReady() {
    $("#divArea").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#areasCovered").fadeToggle(1000);

        if (document.getElementById("h3Class").value = "View Areas Covered -" == true) {
            document.getElementById("h3Class").innerHTML = "View Areas Covered +";
        }; else {

        }
    });
 }

$(document).ready(onReady);
```

Next, we try to simplify your code a bit:

```
function onReady() {
    $("#divArea").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#areasCovered").fadeToggle(1000);

        // use local variable when you can
        var elementToReplace = document.getElementById("h3Class");

        // look closely at this if statement,
        // you should see 2 incorrect things
        if (elementToReplace.value = "View Areas Covered -" == true) {
            elementToReplace.innerHTML = "View Areas Covered +";
        }; else {

        }
    });
 }

$(document).ready(onReady);
```

Your `if` has the following form: `if (a.b = "c" == true)`. This is a valid JavaScript statement, but definitely not what you want to do. I guess you want that instead: `if (a.b === "c")`.
So let's rewrite this `if` statement, and put curly braces in new lines:

```
if (elementToReplace.value === "View Areas Covered -")
{
    elementToReplace.innerHTML = "View Areas Covered +";
};
else
{
}
```

Did you see the pending `;` after the `}` of the `if` ? That's incorrect.

Finally, here's what you could have done:

```
// when in doubt with your code, it's a bit better to
// externalize your "document.ready" code in a named function
function onReady() {
    $("#divArea").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#areasCovered").fadeToggle(1000);

        // use local variable when you can
        var element = document.getElementById("h3Class");

        if (element.value === "View Areas Covered -")
        {
            element.innerHTML = "View Areas Covered +";
        }
        else
        {
            element.innerHTML = "something else";
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(onReady);
```

Comment: Using your code, on the second click, the text does not return to a +

Comment: it's normal... When the value is `xxx -`, you set to `xxx +`, but when it's not you set it to `something else` (well I set it in my code **example**). Did you read my code at least ?!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, what you need is to show / hide the list of areas, and change the title according to the visibility of the areas list, i.e if the areas is hiding show the +, and if it's viisble, show the minus.

You can do it with this little code:

```
<div class="well well-sm">                  
    <div id="divArea" class="img-responsive" >
        <a href="#" id="toggle"><h3>View Areas Covered -</h3></a>
        <div id ="areasCovered" class="img-responsive">
            <p  class="paragraph1"> //list of cities </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this javascript:

```
$('#toggle').click(function() {
    $('#areasCovered').stop(true,true);
    var visible = $('#areasCovered').is(':visible')
    $('#areasCovered').fadeToggle(1000);
    var $title= $('#divArea').find('h3');
    $title.text(visible
                ? 'View Areas Covered +'
                : 'View Areas Covered -');
});
```

[Look the JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jbustos/arvLrrfw/).

Comment: But the text in the JSFiddle is not returing to a +, which is what I need

Comment: It's working now. I dit it originally with `toggle` and it was working fine, but then I changed it to fadeToggle`` and borke it. It's now working again.

Comment: I further updated the code: now the + and minus appaear when they have to, and, if you click the link before the toggle has completed, it works fine. BTW, I'd do a faster `fadeToggle`, 1 second is way too slow. Does this solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#divArea").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#areasCovered").fadeToggle(1000);
            var button = $("#h3Class");
            if(button.html() == "View Areas Covered +")
                button.html("View Areas Covered -");
            else
                button.html("View Areas Covered +");
        }); 
    });
```

So I've made a few fixes and optimisations.

- DOM requests are expensive, not hugely but its good practise to keep them to a minimum. So I've stored the element as a variable so we have 1 requests not 2.
- Swapped the DOM request to jQuery as your already using it.
- Now only registering one listener to the button, with a toggle if statement.